# Cross-table UPDATE in SQLITE3

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-update

In `SQL Server`, I can do something like this:

```
UPDATE tbl1 
   SET col2 = tbl2.col2 
  FROM table1 tbl1 
 INNER JOIN table2 tbl2 
    ON tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1
```

I haven't bothered to look whether this is part of any SQL standard or not, and I'm sure there are other ways to do it, but it is *astoundingly* useful.

Here's my problem. I need to do something similar *in SQL* (i.e, not a host language) with SQLITE3. Can it be done?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This works for sqlite:

```
UPDATE tbl1 SET col2 = (SELECT col2 FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.col1 = tbl1.col1)
```

Comment: not very helpful if you have multiple columns you want to set from the same row in the second table.

Comment: @Michael it answer his question perfectly, if you have a different problem you wish to solve, ask a new question.

Comment: But,Beware this will set tbl1's Col2 to null if no matching row is found in tbl2.

Comment: what happens if the inner query returns >1 row?

Answer (score 5):

Just to emphasize Geogory Higley's post:

I have had problems with `UPDATE tbl1 SET col2 = (SELECT col2 FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.col1 = tbl1.col1)` where it updates columns in tbl1 that do not exist in tbl2.

see cheetah post at http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/1708/7238.aspx which points to:

http://www.mail-archive.com/sqlite-users@sqlite.org/msg27207.html

The code is:

```
insert or replace into foo (id, name, extra)
select bar.id, bar.name, foo.extra
  from bar 
  left join foo 
    on bar.id = foo.id;
```

and this seems to work correctly. There seem to be many posts at different sites that recommend the first approach so it is a bit confusing. I would suggest you test your output very carefully if you use this method which does seem faster and may work with matched tables.

Comment: "I have had problems with UPDATE tbl1 SET col2 = (SELECT col2 FROM tbl2 WHERE tbl2.col1 = tbl1.col1) where it updates columns in tbl1 that do not exist in tbl2."how can you update a column in table 1 to a column in tbl2 that does not exist in tbl2?? isn't this request a bit invalid?

Comment: This solution is dangerous! it requires foo and bar tables to have the same number of columns or it will replace any extra fields in foo table with NULLs

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered this can be done with `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO`. A little more verbose than T-SQL's equivalent, but just as handy.

Comment: Can you provide your solution?

Comment: @HannesdeJager Check out the new answer, I found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, Microsoft SQL Server and MySQL are the only brands of database that support multi-table updates, and the syntax each uses is not similar.

This feature is not part of standard SQL.  So it's not surprising that support for multi-table update (and delete) is nonstandard and not supported by many brands.

Anyway, I'm glad you found a solution that works for your task.

Comment: wouldn't SQL Server and MySQL combined represent a very large part of all databases in production? I'd guess at-least two thirds, maybe some Oracle being the other. This comment makes it seem as if the request is "out of the ordinary", but in fact it is supported by most prod databases.

Comment: @Tommy, since the multi-table update syntax of Microsoft is not compatible with the multi-table update syntax of MySQL, I don't think it's fair to group them together.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 3.33, SQLite supports the `UPDATE FROM` idiom, however in a slightly different flavour than that of SQL Server: the target table must not be listed in the `FROM` cause, meaning that joins with it must be done in a `WHERE` clause.

Your example becomes:

```
UPDATE tbl1 
   SET col2 = tbl2.col2 
  FROM tbl2
 WHERE tbl1.col1 = tbl2.col1
```