# How do I merge two sqlite tables using a "where" condition?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables. One of them has three columns "word", "count", and "value". The second one has two columns "word" and "value". In the second table, every field of the value column has an attached integer value. In the first table, the "value" column is empty or with placeholder values.

I want to import the values of the second table column "value" into the first table column "value" by matching the "word" column.

For a single row, the command would be something like

`update table1 set 'value' = "valuefromTable2" where 'word' = "matchingWordFromTable2";`

Since I have around 200k rows to update, I would rather use a potential SQLite feature (merge?)than a piece of code doing the work row by row. Do you know how to achieve that?

Comment: Can you show the table layout, example values and example result? This sounds a lot like a join.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-table UPDATE in SQLITE3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329197/cross-table-update-in-sqlite3)

Comment: indeed, both Gordon Linoff answer and  Cross-table UPDATE in SQLITE3 works. Note that Gordon forgot the dot between "table2" and "t2"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery in the `update`:

```
update table1
    set 'value' = (select value from table2 t2 where table1.word = t2.word);
```

Comment: Thanks, I assume it works but it freezes every SQLite Browser I have and takes forever to be performed. I ended up doing a piece of code where I fill two datatables with my tables, merge them in a third, and create a SQLite table from scratch. Not the best way, but easiest/fastest in my case

Comment: @Billybobbonnet . . . You probably just need an index on `table2(word)`.

Comment: I was sure I had one on the word column. After checking, I hadn't. Since I never used tables with 500k records, I assumed it was because of its size. My bad :-)