# SQL - update main table using temp table

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sql-update

I have a question about SQL, especially SQLite3. I have two tables, let's name them `main_table` and `temp_table`. These tables are based on the same relational schema so they have the same columns but different rows (values).

Now what I want to do:

For each row of the `main_table` I want to replace it if there is a row in a `temp_table` with the same ID. Otherwise I want to keep the old row in the table.

I was thinking about using some `joins` but it does not provides the thing I want.

Would you give me an advice?

EDIT: ADITIONAL INFO:

I would like to avoid writing all columns because those tables conains tens of attributes and since I have to update all columns it couldn't be necessary to write out all of them.

Comment: Quite similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329197/cross-table-update-in-sqlite3

Comment: No clue about sqlite, but it smells like it's a job for either a `MERGE` or an `UPDATE` with a subselect.

Comment: Why subselect, @Thomas Tschernich? Just update.

Comment: Well if you update a table A with data from table B you will need a subselect in your update. Or you do a fancy update join like in MSSQL in case it is allowed in sqlite.

Comment: `update m set m.col1 = t.col1 ... from main_table m inner join temp_table t  on m.id = t.id` where you update all columns excepot `id`, @Thomas Tschernich.

Comment: See, that's the fancy update join I was talking of. I wish I had this in Oracle.

Comment: According the edit you can try second option - create new table with all IDs that match between `temp_table` and `main_table`. Delete rows from `main_table` base on IDs in the new table. Insert rows into `main_table` from `temp_table` based on the same criterion.

Comment: Sorry, @ThomasTschernich, I don't see anything fancy. He must list all columns (with "..." I mean list all columns). This is just SQL. Sorry, but I don't understand your point about "fancy".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the tables have the same structure, you can simply use `SELECT *`:

```sql
BEGIN;

DELETE FROM main_table
WHERE id IN (SELECT id
             FROM temp_table);

INSERT INTO main_table
SELECT * FROM temp_table;

COMMIT;
```

(This will also add any new rows in `temp_table` that did not previously exist in `main_table`.)

Comment: Nice! Thank you! Elegant ant simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 approaches:

1. Update current rows inside `main_table` with data from `temp_table`. The relation will be based by ID.
2. Add a column to `temp_table` to mark all rows that have to be transferred to `main_table` or add aditional table to store `IDs` that have to be transferred. Then delete all rows that have to be transferred from table `main_table` and insert corresponding rows from `temp_table` using column with marks or new table.