# Updating an SQL table while searching another SQL table

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I have an SQL database "Garage.db" that has 3 tables:
Customer, Car and MOT

I want to update the field BookedMOT in the MOT table when someone has entered a Registration that is in the Car table. Can someone help me with the SQL query that can do this, thank you.

I am coding this in python 3.6 using tkinter. Here is my attempt,

```
    def Booked(self):
        date = Date.get()
        month = Month.get()
        year = Year.get()
        BookedMOT = (date + '/' + month + '/' + year)
        Registration = self.RegistrationEnt.get()
        with sqlite3.connect('Garage.db') as db:
            cursor = db.cursor()

        add_date = ('UPDATE MOT SET MOT.BookedMOT = ? FROM Car WHERE Car.Registration = ?')
        cursor.execute(add_date,[(BookedMOT), (Registration)])
        db.commit()
```

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: cursor.execute(add_date,[(BookedMOT), (Registration)])
sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error

Comment: Updates don't deal with multiple tables. What are you conceptually trying to do here? You can't specify a row from the MOT table using constraints on the Car table. Perhaps you want something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329197/cross-table-update-in-sqlite3

Comment: I don't have BookedMOT in the Car table, so I'm not sure. I'm relatively new to coding but I was thinking of maybe using JOIN?

Comment: Show us the definitions of the SQL tables and maybe explain a bit of the reasoning behind them, particularly how they're related.

Comment: CarID is the primary key of the Car table and the foreign key of the MOT and Customer tables is also CarID.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and your desired output. (See [How to
format SQL tables in a Stack Overflow
post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96125) for how to add some.)

Answer (score 0):

(this addresses some Python problems I noticed before even realising that the SQL didn't look right, which should probably be fixed first)

Try this:

```
with sqlite3.connect('Garage.db') as db:
    db.execute(add_date, (BookedMOT, Registration))
```

In general, when you say `with ... as x:`, you should probably use `x` inside the `with` block. After the block finished it did an automatic commit and trying to use `db` or `cursor` afterwards is probably incorrect. The `with` also means that you don't have to `db.commit()` any more.

[sqlite3 connection objects (`db` in this case) have an `execute` method:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.execute)

> This is a nonstandard shortcut that creates a cursor object by calling the cursor() method, calls the cursor’s execute() method with the parameters given, and returns the cursor.

Finally, you had some redundant parentheses that could be removed.

Comment: I still get this error, db.execute(add_date, (BookedMOT, Registration))sqlite3.OperationalError: near ".": syntax error –